# Flutter Image_picker works when running on usb tethered but not app store

Tags: android, flutter

I am using a simple implementation of image_picker. This works fine when running on a usb tethered device through visual studio code however when I use 'flutter build appbundle' and upload it for internal testing to google play store the camera functions seem to not work at all.

I can go through the taking of a picture/video, previewing and selecting ok but after that the rest of the function fails.

```
  _imgFromCamera() async {
    final String rand = '${new Random().nextInt(10000)}';
    final videoName = 'video$rand';
    final image = await picker.getVideo(
      source: ImageSource.camera,
      maxDuration: const Duration(seconds: 10),
    );

    setState(() {
      _image = File(image.path);
    });

    try {
      await _storage
          .ref()
          .child('video/' + videoName)
          .putFile(_image)
          .onComplete;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }
```

**Pubspec**

```
  image_picker: ^0.6.7+14

  firebase_storage: ^3.0.0
  firebase_core: ^0.4.4
  cloud_firestore: ^0.13.1
```

firebase is being used to store the photos.

Comment: Do you get a specific error message? Does it save videos to Firebase storage when tethered? Do you need to perform the Android setup from the image_picker package?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

Create a holder for the video file:

```
File _video; // Only allow one video
```

On a button tap, get the video from the user's camera:

```
Future getvideo() async {
ImagePicker picker = ImagePicker();
PickedFile pickedFile;

// Let user take video with camera
pickedFile = await picker.getVideo(
  source: ImageSource.camera,
  maxDuration: const Duration(seconds: 10),
);

setState(() {
  if (pickedFile != null) {
   _video = File(pickedFile.path);
  } else {
    print('No video selected.');
  }
 });
}
```

Use another button to submit the file:

```
// Upload video
if(_video != null) {
  await saveVideoFromFile(_video);
}
```

The saveVideoFromFile function looks like this:

```
Future<void> saveVideoFromFile(File _video) async {
  String videoURL = await uploadVideo(_video);
  print(videoURL);
}
```

The uploadVideo function:

```
Future<String> uploadVideo(File _video) async {
    StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.instance
        .ref()
        .child('videos/${Path.basename(_video.path)}');
    try {
      StorageUploadTask uploadTask = storageReference.putFile(_video);
      await uploadTask.onComplete;
      print('File Uploaded');
      String returnURL;
      await storageReference.getDownloadURL().then((fileURL) {
        returnURL = fileURL;
      });
      return returnURL;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      return "Error";
    }
  }
```

I'm wondering if thing's are crashing because you're grabbing the image and saving it to Cloud Storage in the same function.